# Perfomance Out parameter vs Out system ref cursor Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sys-refcursor, out-parameters

I have a Procedure in oracle with 12 parameters 4 of them are sys ref cursor.
 I am replace one cursor from my procedure using 8 more out parameters.
 Will there be any performance enhancement if use out parameters instead of out ref cursor.

Answer (score 1):

A cursor can be thought of as a pointer to an area of memory within the database that contains a result set - it does not directly contain the results; so when you send a cursor you are just sending the pointer and then whatever user interface you are using will have to make additional round-trips to the database to use that cursor (pointer) to open the result set, fetch rows and then, when you are finished, close the cursor.

When you use an out parameter with individual values then the values can all be returned as the procedure terminates and no additional communication with the database is required.

> Will there be any performance enhancement if use out parameters instead of out ref cursor.

So, yes, there may be a performance enhancement if you are returning multiple out parameters rather than a cursor which refers to a result set with a single row. However, as with all performance enhancements, you should profile the changes so that you can see the actual effect (which may be negligible).

Comment: Thanks or the response. But if the call of the procedure is per second 10 to 15 times then the effect will be significant?

Comment: @शेखर I do not know your database setup, whether you are making requests across a network or on the local machine, etc.. As I said, profile your current set-up, try changing it and profile the modified set-up and see for yourself what the effect is - no-one else can tell you what the effect will be as we don't have access to your databases/hardware.